# Exporting membership type and contribution total amount

Tags: civimember, civireport, price-sets

An organization sells a variety of membership types.   The goal is to generate an exported CSV that will contain name, address, membership type, and amount paid for that membership.

Two types of memberships are the same price, and CiviDiscount is in use regardless.  Thus total amount of the membership contribution is not a reliable way to determine which membership type someone has purchased.

Unless I use price sets and the 'extended reports' extension from Eileen, I cannot find a way to export "membership type (membership)" as well as "total amount (contribution)" data in the same CSV export.

But this extended report doesn't contain address.  So time to expand that report I guess?

Am I missing an easier solution here?

[image]

Comment: Is a Drupal View an option?

Comment: You could export the view to a csv with View Data Export

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried this (at Stoob's request) on one report & it seemed to only require a couple of lines -

https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport/commit/fb5ba0d47b1c4fea651fcec5760497bf204c5b56

Note that there are several price set reports & this might not be the one you were focussed on but the principle should be the same

Answer (score 0):

I do think expanding the report might be the way forward. If you are developer you could expand on Eileens extension and expand the report code in that extension. That way you also giving back to the community!